# Apache 2.4.x with IP blacklist slow to start

Tags: ip, apache2.4, blacklist

I'm trying to block some specific countries in Apache 2.4.x.
I downloaded the list of IPs from https://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker, put them in a separate file and included it the httpd.conf file.

The size of this file is 8.5MB and it seems to significantly slow down the Apache 2.4 startup time. In particular, it increased from few seconds (without the block list) to few minutes (with the block list). Sometimes, the server fails to start.

Is there a way to speed up the server startup time?

Thank you

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the IP address list is huge, you can consider to block it from different application layer.

1. Firewall - such as ipconfig
2. Web server - such as Apache2 and nginX. You are working on it now.
3. Application - such as PHP page and query a database